# Select Schema and table in sqlserver with Yii2?

Tags: php, sql-server, yii2, sqlsrv

i have sql server database which have multiple schema. i tried to select from one of table from different schema using sqlsrv driver but is says invalid configuration, The table does not exist. 
how can i select the schema in table using sqlsrv driver?

myconnection

```
<?php 
    return [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'sqlsrv:Server=192.168.10.70;Database=mydatabase', // MS SQL Server, sqlsrv driver public ip
        'username' => 'user_username',
        'password' => 'user_password',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ];
?>
```

my model

```
<?php
    namespace app\models;

    use Yii;
    use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

    class Transaction extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
    {
        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        public static function tableName()
        {
            return 'schema2.transaction';
        }

        public static function getDb()
        {
            return \Yii::$app->db3;  // use the "db3" application component
        }

        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        public function rules()
        {
            return [[['id', 'number', 'amount', 'date', 'status', 'description'], 'required']];
        }

        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        public function attributeLabels()
        {
            return [
            'id' => Yii::t('app', 'Uid'),
            'number' => Yii::t('app', 'Number'),
            'date' => Yii::t('app', 'Date'),
            'amount' => Yii::t('app', 'Amount'),
            'description' => Yii::t('app', 'Item Description'),
            'status' => Yii::t('app', 'status'),
            ];
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Did you can using Yii2 Migrate for create table into SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i found the answer. I can't access it because the database is using sqlserver 2000 and my driver did not compatible with it. After i migrate it to sql server 2008 everything crystal clear. Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 3):

The full table name in MS SQL contains three parts: schema, owner, and table name, for example:

```
dbo.user1.table1
```

This means that the `table1` was created by `user1` in the schema `dbo`.

If you don't know the owner or it is default user (`sa`), you can pass it like this:

```
dbo..table1
```

So I suggest you to try out

```
return 'schema2..transaction';
```

or

```
return 'schema2.YOUR_USER_NAME_HERE.transaction';
```

for the correct resolving the table name from different schema.

Comment: tried your solution, using schema2..transaction returned SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Cannot use empty object or column names. Use a single space if necessary.
2nd solution return Invalid object name

Comment: this is weird, when i try schema2.xxx it returned Invalid object name that is because there is no table xxx but when i tried schema2.transaction it said table not exist. is it bug in yii?

Comment: I've tried to create table into SQL Server through Yii Migrate, but It only contain 2 parts, example: root.user. It cause an Issue when using GII, because GII can read any table in the database, how do I can make the table can contain three part, example: dbo.root.user?

Comment: You probably should ask your own question, not comment other's answers